# how to extend properly the Audio Worklet in flutter

Tags: javascript, flutter, web-audio-api, audio-worklet

I have some code that calculates the volume and returns it to a flutter app via the dart js package. this only works for web, apparently the code its working and I get a correct stream of volume data. However I keep getting this message in the terminal

[image: Error]

I don't know what can be wrong? I am loading the js files in the index.

this error is showing in the chrome terminal.